# Is it possible to declare a maximum queue size with AMQP?

Tags: amqp

As the title says — is it possible to declare a maximum queue size and broker behaviour when this maximum size is reached? Or is this a broker-specific option?

I ask because I'm trying to learn about AMQP, not because I have this specific problem with any specific broker… But broker-specific answers would still be insightful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you can't declare maximum queue size with RabbitMQ.

Also there's no such setting in the AMQP sepc:

http://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-quickref.html#queue.declare

Comment: Mmm… Interesting. So how does the administrator of a high-volume AMQP broker ensure that Bad Things don't happen if a consumer disappears?

Comment: RabbitMQ implements a couple of extensions to the protocol: 

Per-Queue Message TTL and Queue Leases. See here: 

http://www.rabbitmq.com/extensions.html#queue-ttl

Answer (score 6):

Depending on why you're asking, you might not actually need a maximum queue size.  Since version 2.0 RabbitMQ will seamlessly persist large queues to disk instead of storing all the messages in RAM.  So if your concern the broker crashing because it exhausts its resources, this actually isn't much of a problem in most circumstances - assuming you aren't strapped for hard disk space.

In general this persistence actually has very little performance impact, because by definition the only "hot" parts of the queue are the head and tail, which stay in RAM; the majority of the backlog is "cold" so it makes little difference that it's sitting on disk instead.

We've recently discovered that [at high throughput it isn't quite that simple](http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/09/24/sizing-your-rabbits/) - under some circumstances the throughput can deteriorate as the queue grows, which can lead to unbounded queue growth.  But when that happens is a function of CPU, and we went for quite some time without hitting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about RabbitMQ maximum queue implementation here http://www.rabbitmq.com/maxlength.html

They do not block the incoming messages addition but drop the messages from the head of the queue.

You should definitely read about Flow control here:
http://www.rabbitmq.com/memory.html

Answer (score 1):

With qpid, yes
you can confire maximun queue size and politic in case raise the maximum. Ring, ignore messages,broke connection.
you also have lvq queues (las value) very configurable

Answer (score 0):

There are some things that you can't do with brokers, but you can do in your app. For instance, there are two AMQP methods, basic.get and queue.declare, which return the number of messages in the queue. You can use this to periodically get a count of outstanding messages and take action (like start new consumer processes) if the message count gets too high.